# Convert dot-separated values into Go structs using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, go, recursion

This is a specific requirement for a application whose configurations can be changed (Specifically the WSO2 Identity Server since I'm writing a Kubernetes operator for it using Go). But it's really not relevant here. I want to create a solution which would allow to easily manage a lot of config mappings to generate Go structs. These configs are mapped within a .csv

Link to .csv - [my_configs.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EeHNEt1XWdWQXa7WCFgdU_fczUW__4kC/view?usp=sharing)

I want to,
**write a python script that would automatically generate the Go structs** so that any change to the application configs could be updated by creating the corresponding Go structs by simply executing the python script. I'm referring to the configs of the application itself. For example, the toml key names in the csv can be changed/new values can be added.

I have been successful so far to create a python script that **nearly achieves my goal**. The script is,

```
import pandas as pd

def convert_to_dict(data):
    result = {}
    for row in data:
        current_dict = result
        for item in row[:-1]:
            if item is not None:
                if item not in current_dict:
                    current_dict[item] = {}
                current_dict = current_dict[item]
    return result

def extract_json_key(yaml_key):
    if isinstance(yaml_key, str) and '.' in yaml_key:
        return yaml_key.split('.')[-1]
    else:
        return yaml_key

def add_fields_to_struct(struct_string,go_var,go_type,json_key,toml_key):
    struct_string += str(go_var) + " " + str(go_type) + ' `json:"' + str(json_key) + ',omitempty" toml:"' +str(toml_key) + '"` ' + "\n"
    return struct_string

def generate_go_struct(struct_name, struct_data):
    struct_name="Configurations" if struct_name == "" else struct_name
    struct_string = "type " + struct_name + " struct {\n"
    yaml_key=df['yaml_key'].str.split('.').str[-1]
    
    # Base case: Generate fields for the current struct level    
    for key, value in struct_data.items():
        selected_rows = df[yaml_key == key]

        if len(selected_rows) > 1:
            go_var = selected_rows['go_var'].values[1]
            toml_key = selected_rows['toml_key'].values[1]
            go_type=selected_rows['go_type'].values[1]
            json_key=selected_rows['json_key'].values[1]
        else:
            go_var = selected_rows['go_var'].values[0]
            toml_key = selected_rows['toml_key'].values[0]
            go_type=selected_rows['go_type'].values[0]
            json_key=selected_rows['json_key'].values[0]

        # Add fields to the body of the struct
        struct_string=add_fields_to_struct(struct_string,go_var,go_type,json_key,toml_key)   

    struct_string += "}\n\n"
    
    # Recursive case: Generate struct definitions for nested structs
    for key, value in struct_data.items():
        selected_rows = df[yaml_key == key]

        if len(selected_rows) > 1:
            go_var = selected_rows['go_var'].values[1]
        else:
            go_var = selected_rows['go_var'].values[0]

        if isinstance(value, dict) and any(isinstance(v, dict) for v in value.values()):
            nested_struct_name = go_var
            nested_struct_data = value
            struct_string += generate_go_struct(nested_struct_name, nested_struct_data)
    
    return struct_string

# Read excel
csv_file = "~/Downloads/my_configs.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

# Remove rows where all columns are NaN
df = df.dropna(how='all')
# Create the 'json_key' column using the custom function
df['json_key'] = df['yaml_key'].apply(extract_json_key)

data=df['yaml_key'].values.tolist() # Read the 'yaml_key' column
data = pd.DataFrame({'column':data}) # Convert to dataframe

data=data['column'].str.split('.', expand=True) # Split by '.'

nested_list = data.values.tolist() # Convert to nested list
data=nested_list 

result_json = convert_to_dict(data) # Convert to dict (JSON)

# The generated co code
go_struct = generate_go_struct("", result_json)

# Write to file
file_path = "output.go"
with open(file_path, "w") as file:
    file.write(go_struct)
```

The problem is (look at the below part of the csv),

```
authentication.authenticator.basic
authentication.authenticator.basic.parameters
authentication.authenticator.basic.parameters.showAuthFailureReason
authentication.authenticator.basic.parameters.showAuthFailureReasonOnLoginPage
authentication.authenticator.totp
authentication.authenticator.totp.parameters
authentication.authenticator.totp.parameters.showAuthFailureReason
authentication.authenticator.totp.parameters.showAuthFailureReasonOnLoginPage
authentication.authenticator.totp.parameters.encodingMethod
authentication.authenticator.totp.parameters.timeStepSize
```

Here since the fields `parameters` are repeated for `basic` and `totp`, the script confuses itself and produces two `TotpParameters` structs. The expected outcome is to have `BasicParameters` and `TotpParameters` structs. Many similar repeating words are present in the csv's `yaml_key` column.

I understand this has something to do with the index being hardcoded as 1 in `go_var = selected_rows['go_var'].values[1]` but have a hard-time fixing this.

Could anyone please point me to an answer? I think,

1. An issue with the recursive function
2. An issue in the code to generate the JSON
   might be a root cause for this issue.

Thanks!

I tried with ChatGPT also, but since this has something to do with nesting and recursion, the provided answers by ChatGPT are not very valid.

**UPDATE**

I found that the problem exists for the rows that contain `properties`, `poolOptions`, `endpoint` and `parameters` fields. This is because they are repeated in the `yaml_key` column.

Comment: 1) Why do you mention JSON? Do you really need to generate Go _source code_ containing definitions of user-defined `struct`s? 2) (If yes), what are the types of the fields of those structs are supposed to be? Some of the input strings _sound_ like boolean values but some sound like requiring string or may be integer types.

Comment: @kostix 1) The pandas would read the csv and create a JSON object first. This JSON is then used to create the Go structs. I don't know if this method is ideal, but did so thinking it made logical sense to first convert to JSON. 2) Yes - each field type is in the column go_type of the csv. A field can be a `string`, `bool` or another custom struct which is defined.

Comment: Does this work, https://xuri.me/toml-to-go/? Or, https://zhwt.github.io/yaml-to-go/?

Comment: @ZachYoung sorry i couldn't mention this in the original post. I've tried these tools but I want to create the Go structs directly by using a python script from the csv as my requirement is to keep the source of truth as the .csv. The output should be gained by executing the python script against it. Does that make sense? Please tell me if not :)

Comment: @RukshanJS, yes makes sense wanting to run it locally. I assumed those sites were backed by libs/utils that were already run-able, but I was wrong. I was thinking of this, https://github.com/PrasadG193/yaml2go, which you can easily and locally execute, although it’s written in Go. But I’m not sure even that will work for you. I was trying to help you avoid (re)writing something that’d already been written.

Comment: @ZachYoung I truly appreciate your effort in helping me. Yes I researched the available solutions for this before doing on my own. But found none since I want my input to be a csv, and the final output be Go structs. Therefore the YAML to Go or JSON to Go libs or code didn't help. I have nearly gotten closer to what i need with above script. But have the slight problem of repeating the go structs for `properties`, `poolOptions`, `endpoint` and `parameters` fields. That's it. All other functionality is as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. But, I had to completely use a new approach to solve the problem, i.e. using a tree data structure and then traversing it. Here's the main logic behind it - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/

Here's the working python code.

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import deque

structs=[]
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []
        self.path=""

    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

def create_tree(data):
    root = TreeNode('')
    for item in data:
        node = root
        for name in item.split('.'):
            existing_child = next((child for child in node.children if child.name == name), None)
            if existing_child:
                node = existing_child
            else:
                new_child = TreeNode(name)
                node.add_child(new_child)
                node = new_child
    return root

def generate_go_struct(struct_data):
    struct_name = struct_data['struct_name']
    fields = struct_data['fields']
    
    go_struct = f"type {struct_name} struct {{\n"

    for field in fields:
        field_name = field['name']
        field_type = field['type']
        field_default_val = str(field['default_val'])
        json_key=field['json_key']
        toml_key=field['toml_key']

        tail_part=f"\t{field_name} {field_type} `json:\"{json_key},omitempty\" toml:\"{toml_key}\"`\n\n"

        if pd.isna(field['default_val']):
            go_struct += tail_part
        else:
            field_default_val = "\t// +kubebuilder:default:=" + field_default_val
            go_struct += field_default_val + "\n" + tail_part

    go_struct += "}\n\n"
    return go_struct

def write_go_file(go_structs, file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        for go_struct in go_structs:
            file.write(go_struct)

def create_new_struct(struct_name):
    struct_name = "Configurations" if struct_name == "" else struct_name
    struct_dict = {
        "struct_name": struct_name,
        "fields": []
    }
    
    return struct_dict

def add_field(struct_dict, field_name, field_type,default_val,json_key, toml_key):
    field_dict = {
        "name": field_name,
        "type": field_type,
        "default_val": default_val,
        "json_key":json_key,
        "toml_key":toml_key
    }
    struct_dict["fields"].append(field_dict)
    
    return struct_dict

def traverse_tree(root):
    queue = deque([root])  
    while queue:
        node = queue.popleft()
        filtered_df = df[df['yaml_key'] == node.path]
        go_var = filtered_df['go_var'].values[0] if not filtered_df.empty else None
        go_type = filtered_df['go_type'].values[0] if not filtered_df.empty else None

        if node.path=="":
            go_type="Configurations"

        # The structs themselves
        current_struct = create_new_struct(go_type)
        
        for child in node.children:  
            if (node.name!=""):
                child.path=node.path+"."+child.name   
            else:
                child.path=child.name

            filtered_df = df[df['yaml_key'] == child.path]
            go_var = filtered_df['go_var'].values[0] if not filtered_df.empty else None
            go_type = filtered_df['go_type'].values[0] if not filtered_df.empty else None
            default_val = filtered_df['default_val'].values[0] if not filtered_df.empty else None

            # Struct fields
            json_key = filtered_df['yaml_key'].values[0].split('.')[-1] if not filtered_df.empty else None
            toml_key = filtered_df['toml_key'].values[0].split('.')[-1] if not filtered_df.empty else None
            
            current_struct = add_field(current_struct, go_var, go_type,default_val,json_key, toml_key)

            if (child.children):
                # Add each child to the queue for processing
                queue.append(child)

        go_struct = generate_go_struct(current_struct)
        # print(go_struct,"\n")        
        structs.append(go_struct)

    write_go_file(structs, "output.go")

csv_file = "~/Downloads/my_configs.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file) 

sample_data=df['yaml_key'].values.tolist()

# Create the tree
tree = create_tree(sample_data)

# Traverse the tree
traverse_tree(tree)
```

Thanks a lot for all of your helps!

Answer (score 0):

Rukshan.  I see you did some work and came up with a solution you like.  I tried it and got some weird errors, still.  Maybe the CSV or the code has changed and it does indeed run without errors for you... I don't know.

I see problems in output like Endpoint being duplicated, and I see Go's basic string type being redefined:

```golang
type string struct {
    FromAddress string `json:"fromAddress,omitempty" toml:"from_address"`
    Username string `json:"username,omitempty" toml:"username"`
    Password string `json:"password,omitempty" toml:"password"`
    Hostname string `json:"hostname,omitempty" toml:"hostname"`
    ...
```

I've worked out a different solution.

Starting with a simple, sample CSV, like:

```
| toml_key | yaml_key | go_var | go_type |
|----------|----------|--------|---------|
| a        | a        | A      | A       |
| a.b      | a.b      | B      | string  |
| a.c      | a.c      | C      | string  |
| a.d      | a.d      | D      | bool    |
| e        | e        | E      | E       |
| e.f      | e.f      | F      | F       |
| e.f.g    | e.f.g    | G      | string  |
| e.h      | e.h      | H      | string  |
```

My program generates the following Go code:

```golang
// Code generated by ... DO NOT EDIT.
package main

type A struct {
    B string `json:"b,omitempty" toml:"b"`
    C string `json:"c,omitempty" toml:"c"`
    D bool   `json:"d,omitempty" toml:"d"`
}

type E struct {
    F struct {
        G string `json:"g,omitempty" toml:"g"`
    } `json:"f,omitempty" toml:"f"`
    H string `json:"h,omitempty" toml:"h"`
}
```

I chose to just create nested structs since I don't see the need for F to be its own type that is referenced in E.  This allowed for a direct approach to parsing the structure from the rows of CSV, and finally generating the Go code.  My program also allows for F and H to be siblings, even with the more-deeply nested G coming before H (in the CSV).

I started with a typed dict named TypeDef:

```py
class TypeDef(TypedDict):
    """A (possible) hierarchy of config values that will be materialized into (possibly nested) Go structs."""

    yaml_key_path: str
    """The original dot-separated YAML key path."""

    toml_name: str
    yaml_name: str
    go_name: str
    go_type: str

    fields: list["TypeDef"]
```

The fields parameter allows me to recursively add more TypeDefs, to mimic nested structs we saw above.

I struggled with the approach to reading the CSV and settled on this:

```py
def add(td: TypeDef, tl_tds: list[TypeDef]):
    """
    Adds td either as a top-level TypeDef, directly to a top-level TypeDef's fields, or to
    a sub-field of a top-level TypeDef.
    """
    print(f"adding {td['yaml_key_path']}")

    path_keys = td["yaml_key_path"].split(".")

    if len(path_keys) == 1:
        tl_tds.append(td)
        return

    tl_key = path_keys[0]
    tl_td: TypeDef | None = None
    for x_td in tl_tds:
        if x_td["yaml_name"] == tl_key:
            tl_td = x_td
            break
    assert tl_td is not None, f"could not find top-level TypeDef with key {tl_key}"

    if len(path_keys) == 2:
        tl_td["fields"].append(td)
        return

    parent_td = tl_td  # rename top-level to parent (same object)

    # Skip top-level key and omit final key.  If not all intermediate keys exist as
    # prescribed by YAML key the last-found parent will be used.
    intermediate_keys = path_keys[1:-1]
    for key in intermediate_keys:
        for child_td in parent_td["fields"]:
            if child_td["yaml_name"] == key:
                parent_td = child_td
                break
    parent_td["fields"].append(td)
```

The function makes special cases for a TypeDef:

- without a parent: just add it to the list of structs
- with just one parent: add it to the fields of the top-level TypeDef
- finally, any number of intermediate (parent) TypeDefs: find the last the parent TypeDef.  Notice the comment about missing intermediate keys/TypeDefs.  Some of the configs specify YAML key paths that don't exist:

  ```
  user_store.connection_password,userStore.connectionPassword,ConnectionPassword,string
  user_store.properties.CaseInsensitiveUsername,userStore.properties.caseInsensitiveUsername,CaseInsensitiveUsername,bool
  ```

  CaseInsensitiveUsername appears to be a child of properties, but properties was never defined on its own, so the program will add CaseInsensitiveUsername directly to userStore, like:

  ```py
  [
      ...
      {
          "yaml_key_path": "userStore",
          "toml_name": "user_store",
          "yaml_name": "userStore",
          "go_name": "UserStore",
          "go_type": "UserStore",
          "fields": [
              {
                  "yaml_key_path": "userStore.type",
                  "toml_name": "type",
                  "yaml_name": "type",
                  "go_name": "Type",
                  "go_type": "string",
                  "fields": [],
              },
              ...
              {
                  "yaml_key_path": "userStore.properties.caseInsensitiveUsername",
                  "toml_name": "CaseInsensitiveUsername",
                  "yaml_name": "caseInsensitiveUsername",
                  "go_name": "CaseInsensitiveUsername",
                  "go_type": "bool",
                  "fields": [],
              },
              ...
          ],
      }
      ...
  ]
  ```

Writing that sample structure above to Go code becomes fairly simple.

I start iterating the top-level TypeDefs (structs) in the list-of-TypeDefs:

```py
w("// Code generated by ... DO NOT EDIT.\n")
w("package main\n")
w("\n")

# Top-level TypeDefs are 'types' in Go
for tl_td in tl_tds:
    w("type ")
    write_td(tl_td)
    w("\n\n")
```

and for each top-level TypeDef, recursively write its fields:

```py
def write_td(td: TypeDef):
    """Write a TypeDef (and recursively its fields)."""

    def write_struct_tag(td: TypeDef):
        w(f"`json:\"{td['yaml_name']},omitempty\" toml:\"{td['toml_name']}\"`")

    w("\n")
    w(td["go_name"] + " ")

    # If not a struct (simple Go type)
    if td["fields"] == []:
        w(td["go_type"])
        return

    # Else a struct
    w("struct {")
    for x_td in td["fields"]:
        write_td(x_td)
        write_struct_tag(x_td)
    w("}")
```

The final Go code looks a bit sloppy:

```golang
// Code generated by ... DO NOT EDIT.
package main

type 
A struct {
B string`json:"b,omitempty" toml:"b"`
C string`json:"c,omitempty" toml:"c"`
D bool`json:"d,omitempty" toml:"d"`}

type 
E struct {
F struct {
G string`json:"g,omitempty" toml:"g"`}`json:"f,omitempty" toml:"f"`
H string`json:"h,omitempty" toml:"h"`}
```

but it has the minimum number of line breaks and spaces to be syntactically correct, which is all Gofmt needs:

```py
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.run(["go", "fmt", "output.go"], check=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f"could not run go fmt output.go: {e}")
```

to make it look like the sample I shared at the top of the post.

You can see all the Python code, CSVs, and generated Go code I used/made in this solution, [here](https://gist.github.com/zacharysyoung/0fafae7fbc5032b87a2115f251e45b86).

In the full code you'll see I don't use Pandas (in my opinion, not the correct application for Pandas), and you'll see me validating each row:

```py
for row in reader:
    for i, x in enumerate(row):
        assert x != "", f"on line {reader.line_num} field {i+1} was empty"
```

because I found a row in my_configs.csv that was missing a Go type:

```
AssertionError: on line 165 field 4 was empty
```

which corresponds to this row:

```
authentication.endpoint.enableMergingCustomClaimMappingsWithDefault,authentication.endpoint.enableMergingCustomClaimMappingsWithDefault,EnableMergingCustomClaimMappingsWithDefault,
```

which I believe is missing (and I corrected to) the Go type bool.

Comment: Hi Zach, I super-appreciate your well-put answer! I'll definitely go through this and get back soon! I too want to learn different approaches to solve the problem because I'm interested to learn through this rather than just the working code.